# Can you vertically align text in the middle of the screen?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have to display text in the middle of the screen. So I need the text to be vertically and horizontally aligned in the middle. The horizontal alignment is not a problem, but I don't know how to align it vertically. I have found some solutions, but they need JQuery and I'm not familiar with that yet. The text has to be in the center on every monitor and every resolution.

Comment: [How do I vertically align text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2939914/691711).

Answer (score -1):

I use this css class in all my projects.  Assign the class to any div container and it will show vertically and horizontally centered. Hope this works for you.

```
.windowCentered {
    padding: 10px;
    position : fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: yes that works but you have to scroll on my page and that's not possible due to the fixed position

Answer (score -2):

So I don't know your full situation but do the following (if it helps):

[In your CSS file]
- select your text ("p" or "h1" or whatever you used). Select it by doing the following (assume you wrote your "text" in "

"):

p {

}

- then type the following:

  p {
  text-align: center;
  }

Save the file(s) and reload it and the text should be aligned in the middle

OTHER SITUATION:

DO you mean you want to put it in the center of your WHOLE screen? Then that would be more complicated but I suggest that you try some of these things:

- define how large your website is allowed to be (maximum)
- take the half of this size ()
- nest your text into a container, like
- use CSS to put your "block" into the middle of the screen.
  You'd have to google the rest because unfortunately I'm not a pro. These are the things I'd try!